# what is the use of access column in joomla1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

I have a joomla1.5 based application. In `jos_content` table, there is a column named `access` which is integer type. Its default value is 0. Is it related with accessing the content according to user group? I have below concerns regarding this field:

- I am unable to understand why Joomla use this?
- Should I include this column in the my queries?
- Which type of values it should contains? is there any special meaning of these values?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unable to understand why Joomla use this?

Access level is group of Joomla groups.There are three Access level in Joomla 1.5 and In Joomla 2.5+ there can be any number of access level.

3 levels of access in Joomla 1.5:

1.Public(0) (All users can access this item)

2.Registered(1) (All registered and logged in users can access this item)

3.Special(2) (Only users logged in and assigned to the Author, Editor, Publisher, Manager, Administrator or Super Administrator groups can access this item)

> Should I include this column in the my queries?

Depends on requirement.If you have users assigned to different group than you should have this column and of course query should filter content based on logged in user access level.

> Which type of values it should contains? is there any special meaning
>   of these values?

jos_content save id of access level in access column like 0 for public,1 for registered and 3 for special.